Вопрос по API ключам и картам, Как это теперь работает?
Полтора года назад сделал карту через Конструктор карт Яндкекса.
Получил API ключ геокодера чтоб карта могла определить местоположение пользователя
Вставил эту карту на сайт через блок html .
Какое то время все работало хорошо, почти год, но сейчас уже почти пол года как почему то перестало определяться местоположение пользователя.
Как будто что то изменилось и API ключ Яндекса перестал работать совместно с конструктором карт Яндекса, или как то по другому теперь ключ API соединяется с кодом Конструктора карт Яндекс.
Как можно, и можно ли вообще, теперь соединить интерактивную карту созданную в Конструкторе карт Яндекс с API ключом Яндекса?
В поддержке ответа не получил. Я не программист, и не могу разобраться без подсказки как теперь соединять все это
